# how do i get Ruby FileList to pick up files without a name, like .htaccess on windows

Tags: ruby

I want to search my filesystem for any files with the extension `.template`.

The below works fine for everything except `.htaccess.template`

```
FileList.new(File.join(root, '**', '*.template')).each do |file|
    # do stuff with file
end
```

because windows doesn't like nameless files, grrrr

How do I make this work on Windows? This code works fine on Linux....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
Dir.glob([".*.template", "*.template"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `FileList` here is the `FileList` class from rake then the problem is in Ruby's underlying `Dir` class (which is used by `FileList`) not matching files starting with `.` for the `*` wildcard. The relevant portion of rake.rb is

```
# Add matching glob patterns.
def add_matching(pattern)
  Dir[pattern].each do |fn|
    self << fn unless exclude?(fn)
  end
end
```

Below is an ugly hack that overrides `add_matching` to also include files starting with `.` Hopefully someone else will be along to suggest a more elegant solution.

```
class Rake::FileList
  def add_matching(pattern)
    files = Dir[pattern]
    # ugly hack to include files starting with . on Windows
    if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin/
      parts = File.split(pattern)
      # if filename portion of the pattern starts with * also
      # include the files matching '.' + the same pattern
      if parts.last[0] == ?*
        files += Dir[File.join(parts[0...-1] << '.' + parts.last)]
      end
    end    
    files.each do |fn|
      self << fn unless exclude?(fn)
    end
  end
end
```

**Update:** I have just tested this on Linux here and the files starting with `.` are not included either. e.g. If I have a directory `/home/mikej/root` with 2 subdirectories `a` and `b` where each contains `first.template` and `.other.template` then

```
Rake::FileList.new('home/mikej/root/**/*.template')
=> ["/home/mikej/root/a/first.template", "/home/mikej/root/b/first.template"]
```

so I would double check the behaviour on Linux and verify that there isn't something else causing the difference in behaviour.

Comment: what would be the "alternative way"?

Comment: I haven't found an alternative way as the other methods on `Dir` also behave the same. However see the updated answer for a workaround.

Comment: @Andrew Bullock please see the update I've done describing the result of my testing it on Linux as that also doesn't seem to include the . files - could it be a difference in the version of Ruby on the 2 platforms? I'm on 1.8.6 in both cases.